# Salary class difference SQL statement in HR Sample Databaase

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL query that can show list of all employees with their name, job title, salary and its salary class difference. The latter will give information per employee if their salary is above (signify +) or below (signify -) the average of the salary set for the job (see min_salary and max_salary).

```
SELECT 
  e.employee_id, 
  e.first_name, 
  e.last_name, 
  j.job_title, 
  e.salary,
  CASE WHEN salary>AVG(salary) THEN max_salary - min_salary END AS salary_class_difference
FROM hr.employees e, hr.jobs j
WHERE e.job_id=j.job_id;
```

This is the best I could come up with.

[Sample Database](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-sample-database/)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: This post lacks of question. Can you make what are you looking for explicit please? @LeetRothschild

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 
  e.employee_id, 
  e.first_name, 
  e.last_name, 
  j.job_title, 
  e.salary,
  CASE WHEN salary>(select AVG(salary) from hr.employees) 
  THEN (select max(salary) from hr.employees)-(select min(salary)from 
  hr.employees)) END AS salary_class_difference
  FROM hr.employees e, hr.jobs j
  WHERE e.job_id=j.job_id;
```

Comment: Thanks but that is wrong and I already got the answer. The average is for every job not for everyone.